# log file of script batch

Tags: windows, cmd

```
@echo off
    call :checkFTP1 %* > all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :checkFTP2 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :checkFTP3 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :doCommands1 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :doCommands2 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :doCommands3 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    call :doCommands4 %* >> all_log_all_log_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log 2>&1
    exit /b
    
    
:checkFTP1

    @echo off
Setlocal

:: Is folder empty
set _TMP=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\test\folder1"') do set _TMP="%%a"
IF {%_TMP%}=={} (
    goto :Exit1
) ELSE (
    goto :checkFTP2
)
Endlocal


:checkFTP2
    @echo off
Setlocal

:: Is folder empty
set _TMP=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\test\folder2"') do set _TMP="%%a"
IF {%_TMP%}=={} (
    goto :Exit2
) ELSE (
    goto :checkFTP3
)
Endlocal


:checkFTP3
    @echo off
Setlocal

:: Is folder empty
set _TMP=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\test\folder3"') do set _TMP="%%a"
IF {%_TMP%}=={} (
    goto :Exit3
) ELSE (
    goto :doCommands1
)
Endlocal


:doCommands1
    call script1.bat
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :doCommands2 ) Else ( ECHO error on script 1 ,2,3,4)
    exit
:doCommands2
    call script2.bat
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :doCommands3 ) Else ( ECHO Script 1 Completed  Successfully , ERRORS on  2,3,4)
    exit
:doCommands3
    call script3.bat
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :doCommands4) Else ( ECHO Script 2 Completed  Successfully , ERRORS on 3,4)
    exit
:doCommands4
    call script4.bat
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :completed1) Else ( ECHO Script 3 Completed  Successfully , ERRORS on  4)
    exit
:Exit1 

Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
Echo ###################FTP-1 FILES  MISSING  #########################

Exit

:Exit2

Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
Echo ###################FTP-2 FILES  MISSING (#########################

Exit

:Exit3

Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
Echo ###################FTP-3 FILES  MISSING   #########################

Exit
    
    
:completed1


Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
Echo ###################all scripts  Completed  Successfully#########################

Exit
```

I have above batch file which calls multiple bat files. I have tested the script and it worked fine.
My only issue is that the log file generated contains all information, and it's a large file.
Is it possible to just log comments and echo, and exclude what executed in screen?
For example I don't want 1 file moved to be showing in log file.

Comment: Append `> nul` to the command that produces output (most probably the `move` command in your example). Anyway, you should replace all instances of `exit` by `exit /B`, and you should use `IF "%_TMP%"==""` rather than `IF {%_TMP%}=={}`…

Comment: I guess you are talking about messages generated by the sub-scripts (like `call script1.bat`); to avoid them to be written to the log file, use either `call script1.bat > con` (to display the messages in the console window) or `call script1.bat > nul` (to completely hide the messages)…

Comment: i don't want   bellow to be shwoing   
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
i just need my log file to contain 

Today Date  Fri 10/16/2020  at 13:30:10.39
###################FTP FILES CHECKED  #######################  

Today Date  Fri 10/16/2020  at 13:30:10.41
###################all scripts  Completed  Successfully#############

Comment: then pipe the `move` command's output to nul `>nul 2>&1`

Comment: worked fine thanks for you support .


:doCommands1
    call script1.bat > con 
 if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :doCommands2 ) Else ( ECHO error on script 1 ,2,3,4)
exit /B

Comment: BTW, `dir /b` will not tell you whether the directory is empty! In order to do that you need to include items with all attributes, and the `/A` option will do that, _unless you specify, or exclude, particular ones_, e.g. `Dir /B /A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and re-written it to use generic functions which deduplicates the code into an a more easily managed form and allows you to add or remove any steps to FTP and Script sections as needed by editing the list of variables.

I also only return output that does not include the "file(s) moved".

Alternatively if you really only want the status lines to print you could change this to just have those print to the log and not have all info print to the log (this is being done because you are putting the redirection to the log on the calls to other steps.

Also the way this was written before it was actually going through all the goto commands and not needing the calls to each at the top.

Here is the refactored code, I haven't tested it but it should be fine I have to step out for a few hours and you can ask any questions and I'll be happy to answer when I have time.

```cmd
@( Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
  echo off
  SET "_FolderList="C:\test\folder1" "C:\test\folder1" "C:\test\folder1" "
  SET "_ScriptList="c:\test\script1.bat" "E:\script2.bat" "C:\Path\To\script3.bat" "C:\Path\To\script4.bat" "
  SET "_Scripts_Failed=1,2,3,4"
  SET "_Scripts_Completed="
  SET "_Continue=0"
  CALL :GetDateTime
  SET "MasterLog=all_log_all_log_!IsoDate!_!IsoTime!.log"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  SET /A "_Counter=0"
  FOR %%_ IN (%_FolderList%) DO (
    IF DEFINED _Continue (
      SET /A "_Counter+=1"
      CALL :CheckFTP_List %%~_
    )
  )>> "%MasterLog%"
  SET /A "_Counter=0"
  FOR %%_ IN (%_FolderList%) DO (
    IF DEFINED _Continue (
      SET /A "_Counter+=1"
      CALL :DoCommands_List %%~_
    )
  )>> "%MasterLog%"
  IF DEFINED _Continue (
    Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
    Echo ###################all scripts  Completed Successfully#########################
  )
GOTO :EOF
  
  
:CheckFTP_List
  REM Is folder empty
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /A-D "%*') do (
    set "_Continue=%%a" )
  IF NOT Defined _Continue (
    Echo.Today Date on %DATE%  at %Time%
    Echo.###################FTP-%_Counter% FILES  MISSING  #########################
  )
GOTO :EOF

:DoCommands_List
  call "*%" | FIND /I /V "file(s) moved" &REM only outputs lines that don't contain files moved.
  if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    SET "_Continue="
    SET "_Scripts_Completed=%_Scripts_Completed:,1=1%"
    SET "_Scripts_Failed=!_Scripts_Failed:%_Scripts_Completed%=!"
    Echo Today Date  %DATE%  at %Time%
    ECHO. Error encountered on Script %Counter%! -- Completed Scripts: !_Scripts_Completed! -- Failed Scripts: !_Scripts_Failed!
  ) ELSE (
    SET "_Scripts_Completed=%_Scripts_Completed:,1=1%,%Counter%"
  )
GOTO :EOF



:GetDateTime
  FOR /F "Tokens=1-7 delims=MTWFSmtwfsouehrandit:-\/. " %%A IN ("%DATE% %TIME: =0%") DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=2-4 Delims=(-)" %%a IN ('ECHO.^| DATE') DO (
      SET "%%~a=%%~A"
      SET "%%~b=%%~B"
      SET "%%~c=%%~C"
      SET "HH=%%~D"
      SET "Mn=%%~E"
      SET "SS=%%~F"
      SET "Ms=%%~G"
    )
  )
  SET "IsoTime=%HH%.%Mn%.%SS%.%Ms%"
  SET "IsoDate=%yy%-%mm%-%dd%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: @stephan a find and replace issue!  Thanks for noting, will fix from phone now

Comment: Currently my issue is that   I need to replace script to in to other location and I still have to call it  ,  which means in my main script I have to call difrent scripts stored  in  different locations .
I use 
cd c:\test
call script1.bat

However   I am not bale to call second script which is in different  location 
cd: E:
Call script2.bat 

Script1  is executed fine the issues is that script 2 is not executed do I need to do something else to switch between paths rather than just CD: path before calling script

Comment: `call "c:\test\script1.bat"`, `call "E:\script2.bat"` (read the ouput of `cd /?` and use the `/d` switch, or use `pushd` if changing to the folders is really neccessary)

Comment: @Stephan   kindly can you write me example   pls

Comment: uhm - didn't I?

Comment: @Stephan  yes its clear thanks a lot   , just last query if you don't mind pls . in the log file generated , i see the commands written in the log , is it possible to hide . i really appreciate your support .

Comment: That shouldn't happen with `echo off`. Did you parhaps forget to change an `echo on` (for troubleshooting) back to `echo off` somewhere?

Comment: THANKS ALL FOR YOUR SUPPORT

Comment: @h.mustafa  In the code presented in this answer, you jcan include the full path to each script.  eg `  SET "_ScriptList="c:\test\script1.bat" "E:\script2.bat" "C:\Path\To\script3.bat" "C:\Path\To\script4.bat" "`  I have amended, also taking care of one issue I hadn't noted before.